# Why do you need functions such as these (*>) or (<*) if they discard the first or second argument?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, applicative

[The type signature of the function `(*>)`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.0.0/docs/Control-Applicative.html#v:-42--62-) is such:

> ```
> (*>) :: f a -> f b -> f b
> ```
>
> Sequence actions, discarding the value of the first argument.

Can someone please explain why this is useful?  Seems counter-intuitive if the first argument is discarded.

Please illustrate with examples.  Thanks.

Comment: They discard the *result* of the argument, but keep its *effects*, if any. (Pretty sure this is a dup, not sure of what...)

Comment: It's similar to `>>`, in that if you have a function with a side effect, you don't need the result, as it often is `()`, which generally isn't helpful. For example `putStrLn "Input a line:" *> getLine`. It will print "Input a line", prompt for an input, then return the input

Comment: Here's another example, in another applicative: `Nothing *> Just 'a'` gives back `Nothing` (not `Just 'a'`).

Comment: Ahhh!!! Discarding the RESULT.  I was confused because the explanation said "discarding the value".

Comment: I recommend clicking through to the source (in this case some of the instance declarations) if you're not sure what something does or why

Answer (score 9):

Let’s suppose our applicative functor here is already a monad. We might implement `*>` and `<*` like this:

```
x *> y = do
  x
  y

x <* y = do
  result <- x
  y
  return result
```

So you can use `<*` and `*>` to write simple things like:

```
askForNumber :: IO Int
askForNumber = putStr "Please enter a number: " *> readLn <* putStrLn "Thank you."
```

So you can see that while the “result” is discarded, the result is only one part of a monadic action or applicative functor action.

Answer (score 3):

The "shape" of the discarded argument is still used.  Think of an `Applicative f => f a` value as having some values of type `a` arranged in some sort of shape made possible by the applicative functor f.  The operator `<*> :: Applicative f => f (a -> b) -> f a -> f b` combines the shapes of its first two arguments to come up with a third shape.  `pure x` always has a simple 'idenitity' shape that doesn't alter another shape.

The definitions for the two operators in question are equivalent to:

```
a <* b = pure (\x y -> x) <*> a <*> b
a *> b = pure (\x y -> y) <*> a <*> b
```

`pure` expressions have an identity shape, which can be inferred from the first applicative law, `pure id <*> v = v`.  So when `pure (\x y -> ...) <*> a` is evaluated, its result has the same shape as `a`.  It's equivalent to `fmap (\...) a`, whose result also has the same shape as `a`.

Then when `(pure (\x y -> ...) <*> a) <*> b` is evaluated, its result will have the shape of `a` combined with `b`.

There are only two shapes values of `Maybe a` and `Either a b` can take.  They're not that interesting.

```
Prelude> :set +t
Prelude> Just 'x' <* Just (1::Int)
Just 'x'
it :: Maybe Char
Prelude> Just 'x' <* (Nothing :: Maybe Int)
Nothing
it :: Maybe Char
Prelude> (Nothing :: Maybe Char) <* Just (1::Int)
Nothing
it :: Maybe Char
Prelude> (Nothing :: Maybe Char) <* (Nothing :: Maybe Char)
Nothing
it :: Maybe Char
```

For lists, the shape combination is easy to visualize.

```
Prelude> "ab" *> "123"
"123123"
Prelude> "ab" <* "123"
"aaabbb"
```